# AS3 Flash Expandable Banner Go to Next Scene After expanding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, click, banner, expandable

I'll keep this short; basically after my flash banner expands to its normal size I want it to then go to the next scene, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to do this, nothing seems to be working. I'm not that experienced with flash so I probs stuffed up something easy

Link to file: http://www.mediafire.com/?bwz6js3x1autttz

**EDIT**

Heres the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

stop();

hotSpot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, up0);
function up0(e:Event):void
{
     dropDown.gotoAndPlay("down");
     ExternalInterface.call('javascript:expand();');
     play();
}
```

Comment: Generally you will get better responses if you include small snippets of the code you're having problems with, what it already does (or what errors occur), and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
But I found out I actually dont need to use java for the project Im doing, so I managed to quickly fix it up and its working now. Here's the code for anyone who is interested:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
stop();



hotSpot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, up0);
function up0(e:Event):void
{
     dropDown.gotoAndPlay("down");
     play();
}
```